# How to make a startup form invisible and only make it visible if a condition is met

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a made an application that compares the version of files saved on local drive with files saved on the server. Now when i run the app i want it to be invisible as long as the versions are the same..if the files are different it should display the form.with my code below i want the form to be displayed if (result.Count > 0).

```
public void CompareVersion(string local, string remote)
    {   
        List<TinyApps> localResult = GetLocalFileVersionList(local);
        List<TinyApps> remoteResult = GetServerFileVersionList(remote);
        List<TinyApps> result = new List<TinyApps>();

        foreach (TinyApps localfile in localResult)
        {
            foreach (TinyApps remotefile in remoteResult)
            {
                if (localfile.name.ToLower().Equals(remotefile.name.ToLower()))
                {
                    if (!localfile.version.Equals(remotefile.version))
                    {
                        result.Add(remotefile);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (result.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (TinyApps localfile in result)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("Current File not updated:" + localfile.name);
                DisplayUpdate(serverpath, updatefile);
                DownloadFile(serverpath, updatefile);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Updates Available");
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Edit your Main() method in Program.cs.  Simply don't call Application.Run() when you don't want to start the UI.

Comment: @HansPassant then what line of code do i put in the if statement to display the form